# OpenMP with new ecores/pcores

Tags: gcc, openmp

Is there any discussion on how OpenMP could work with new 12th gen Intel ecores and pcores ?
Is this going to be a nightmare for !$omp parallel do, where all threads are expected to have a similar workload ?
I utilise !$OMP BARRIER to synchronise threads to assist in improving cache uiliisation, but if ecores are going to be slower (question?) this approach would fail.
At present, using OpenMP with gfortran on windows does not allow any core locking management.
I am wondering what this new pcore/ecore approach could mean.

Comment: What is ecores and pcores? Do you have any link or description?

Comment: In general `BARRIER` is to be avoided in OpenMP programs. The is core affiny setting in OpenMP.

Comment: @VladimirF, Intel released a new processor where the cores are divided into two classes.   I don't remember the exact terminology, but pcore is, I believe, for performance and ecore is for power-saving.

Comment: Chips with cores differing in performance characteristics are not new and not unique to Intel. Are you interested in wider answers or experience based on these older architectures?

Comment: @VladimirF, I have had good success in reducing cache <> memory delays with this approach, for a large 20GByte shared array. In this case BARRIER is very useful.

Comment: @francescalus, I would be very interested in hearing of any managing mixed cores types. My analysis is !$OMP PARALLEL DO, using gfortran on Windows. For my PARALLEL DO, threads need similar performance to share large arrays in cache. There appears to be little scope for managing core allocation to threads. This could be a problem in restricting lower efficiency "ecores". I have no indication on what the difference is for AVX calculations. I am hoping to see discussions of this or similar hardware used with OpenMP. Ecores look to be another problem that we hope is not a major issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The OpenMP API does not have a specific feature to deal with this situation.  If you know from your system that the P-cores are are cores 0-7 and the E-cores are 8-15, then you can do the following to restrict your OpenMP threads to run only on the P-cores:

In the shell (bash-like):

```
export OMP_PLACES=0-7
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true
```

Then, in your code do something like this (actually no change :-)):

```
!$omp parallel do
do ...
   ...
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

Or in C/C++ syntax:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(...) {...}
```

If you want to span all P and E cores at the same code, you will have to accept some sort of load imbalance, but you could still make good use of them.

In the shell (bash-like):

```
export OMP_PLACES=cores
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true
```

Then, in your Fortran code:

```
!$omp parallel do schedule(nonmonotonic:dynamic,chunkz)
do ...
   ...
end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

Or in C/C++ syntax:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(nonmonotonic:dynamic,chunksz)
for(...) {...}
```

In that case, I would anticipate that a `dynamic` schedule with a chunk size of `chunksz` would a good solution so that the (faster) P-cores get some more work compared to E-cores.

If you use OpenMP tasks, then you might still want to pin the OpenMP threads to cores, but since OpenMP tasks are dynamically scheduled to idling OpenMP threads, you get automatic load balancing.  As a rough rule of thumb you should make sure that you create 10x more tasks than you have OpenMP threads.

Comment: I would at least note that the syntax you use is for C, not Fortran.

Comment: Good point!  I will edit the post.

Comment: when I tried export "OMP_PLACES=0-15" (12700k), it reports OMP_PLACES: syntax error, using "cores"

Comment: You would have to write `OMP_PLACES='{0}:15'` that will give you logical CPUs 0 through 15. See https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpse62.html#x328-5030006.5.